# How do I run a windows program inside an iso file?

Tags: wine, iso

I'm using Lubuntu.

I need to run a windows program which is inside an iso file (no installation required).

The iso contains 2 files: one EXE (small) and one DAT (big).

I have mounted the iso file on `/media/iso`.

I browse the content, I right click on the EXE file and run it with Wine.

It says "No Disc Inserted" and stops.

Then I have mounted it on `/cdrom` and run it with Wine on Terminal (`wine filename.exe`). Same result, it says "No Disc Inserted" and stops.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use one software that provides you to run and extract and so many options (PowerIso). Or other wise you have to mount that file in to removable media and then you have to tap open with new window by right clicking the Disk drive (that you mounted) after that it will shows you all files held in that .ISO file. Simply go and use that ".exe and .bat" files.